# I've clarified my question, can you please consider re-opening it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've edited the following question: I wrote it when I was very tried, and had some typos. I also didn't phrase one sentence right and the question was very un-understandable. I've edited and clarified it. Please consider re-opening:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90238/who-and-when-invented-the-directives-syntax-or-language-used-in-http-conf-and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes there's multiple reasons why a question would be considered off-topic and hence placed on-hold. Initially, the question was pretty *unclear* as you stated above. There are still other reasons however why it would be considered off-topic here:

- Questions on this site are required to be about a [website under your control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and should be specific to an issue or problem that you're facing with that. This question doesn't appear to be about your website, and is more of a research question (like homework) than about an issue or problem you're facing with your website.
- The following request would also be considered [open-ended](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [too broad](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):  `You are also invited to give as much relevant data you can on this language, besides that.`
- Laslty, the [httpd.conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd.conf) (with a "d") and [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) files and their directives, like Apache, were developed by a *community*, so there isn't really a single "woman or man" who invented them, and therefore the question couldn't be answered as such.

So due to the above issues, this question would unfortunately not be considered on-topic or a good fit for this site. I'd recommend reviewing the section on *Asking* under our [Help Center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help) for more information as to [what's considered on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and [what types of questions to avoid asking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Hello Dan, I guess soimeone programmed the Directives language itself or maybe a few people, in a given time... Am II wrong?

Comment: Apache has a long history (since 1995), and evolved from NCSA HTTPd. As you can read about on its [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server):  `Apache is developed and maintained by an open community of developers under the auspices of the Apache Software Foundation` and `hundreds of users have contributed ideas, code, and documentation to the project`. The directives aren't a _language_ per se and were developed as needed, much of it based on system functions and utilities, like regexes from Perl. So it's not really possible to point to anyone in particular.